# Python Discord Bot Scheduled Task Blocks The Rest Of The Code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I build a Discord bot in Python. The bot has some tasks that needs to be run at scheduled different times of the day and some commands that needs to be ran on call.

```
@bot.command(name = "how_are_you", help = "Asks: How Are You?")
async def ask_how_are_you(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How are you?")

@tasks.loop(hours = 24)
async def say_hello():
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(CHANNEL))
    await channel.send("Hello World")

@say_hello.before_loop
async def before():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 20, 00)
    delta = start_time - now
    time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")
```

I then run the bot as follows:

```
say_hello.start()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

How it works: I want `say_hello()` to run every day @ 20.00. The `before()` function takes the current time and checks how many seconds miss before 20.00, it then waits for that amount of seconds.
The issue is that before being able to send commands to the bot, I will need to wait that the `before()` function finishes waiting. This may take a while because if now is 17.00, I'd need to wait until 20.00 before `before()` finishes waiting.
Even worse, if I have a weekly task that runs, let's say, every Friday @ 20.00 and today is Tuesday, I'd need to wait 3 days before being able to send commands.

How can I make the tasks wait in the background and be able in the meanwhile to send the commands to the bot? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve the issue. The `before()` function needs to be changed as follows:

```
@say_hello.before_loop
async def before():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 20, 00)
    delta = start_time - now
    await asyncio.sleep(delta.total_seconds()) #THIS CHANGED
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")
```

What is important, and I didn't do it before, is to remember to `import asyncio` as if you don't do that, the code won't give you any error but it won't work.